# Map @CookieValue, @RequestHeader etc. to POJO in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a bunch of params in my controller and want to map all of them to a separate POJO to keep readability. There is also a @CookieValue, @RequestHeader I need to evaluate and aim for a solution to also map them to that POJO. But how?

I saw a possible solution on a blog but it doesn't work, the variable stays null.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = MAPPING_LANGUAGE + "/category", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String category(CategoryViewResolveModel model) {
    doSomething();
}
```

And my POJO is this:

```
public class CategoryViewResolveModel {

private String pageLayoutCookieValue;

public CategoryViewResolveModel() {
}

public CategoryViewResolveModel(
        @CookieValue(value = "SOME_COOKIE", required = false) String pageLayoutCookieValue) {
    this.pageLayoutCookieValue = pageLayoutCookieValue;
}

... some other RequestParams, PathVariables etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-cookievalue) it's not possible for `@CookieValue` and `@RequestHeader`.

> This annotation is supported for annotated handler methods in Servlet
>   and Portlet environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/
instead of using getParameter to access request parameters you can use getHeader to retrieve the header value and so define your  CategoryViewResolveModel just as you were requesting